# How do you send messages to the window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on a challenge from a self-help book on Cocoa, here is where I'm stuck.
I'm trying to resize the window from a single text field.

```
#import "DelegateAppDelegate.h"

@implementation DelegateAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

//some tip i don't understand from the challenge
-(NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize;
{
    NSSize mySize = NSMakeSize(400, 200);
    NSLog(@"mySize is %f wide and %f tall", mySize.width, mySize.height);
    return mySize;
}

//button that will send the value from the text field
- (IBAction)userResize:(id)sender {

    NSInteger size = [_userSelectedSize intValue];
    NSSize userInputSize = NSMakeSize(size, (size/2)); 
    //there is only one text field named userInputSize. the size is halved
    //for the height

    NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", userInputSize.width, userInputSize.height);
    [_userSelectedSize setStringValue:@"updated"];

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH
    [windowName setHeigth:userInputSize.heigth setWidth:userInputSize.width]
}
@end
```

I would prefer no information on the actual message to send, as I know these parameters are most likely wrong, but I would like to know where to find what to write for the window name.

Please note: The problem is that I don't know where to send the message.

FYI one of my files is named MainMenu.xib if that helps.

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow setHeight:... etc...];`

Comment: (BTW unless you declared and defined such a message, this won't work as-is. You rather want to send a `setFrame:` message.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So with this code replacing it I'm not sure what sharedApplication would be. Ex. `[[DelegateAppDelegate whatGoesHere] setFrame:userInputSize];`

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do with the app delegate. **Don't touch the delegate. You want to access the shared application object.**

Comment: @H2CO3, presumably you mean `NSApplication`, not `UIApplication`.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Yes, that's correct.

Comment: If you want to know what `windowWillResize:toSize:` does, [look it up](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillResize:toSize:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would prefer no information on the actual message to send, as I know these parameters are most likely wrong, but I would like to know where to find what to write for the window name.

Windows don't have names.

A window has a title, but that's displayed to the user—you can't use it to identify the window.

What you need is a way to connect the window in the nib to your code. You need some kind of receptacle in your code that you can plug your window into.

In a word: an *outlet*.

And you probably already have one. Xcode's non-document-based application template includes a `window` outlet in the application delegate, already connected by default. Look in your DelegateAppDelegate header to make sure.

So, you just need to address your `setFrame:display:` message to `self.window`.

Comment: Perfect, `self.window` was exactly what I needed.